# Has anyone encountered this error? read error on /dev/sdc - cannot read sector 0?

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos, lvm, sas

/dev/sdc: read failed after 0 of 1024 at 0: Input/output error 
  /dev/sdc: read failed after 0 of 1024 at 2499819012096: Input/output error 
  /dev/sdc: read failed after 0 of 1024 at 2499819130880: Input/output error 
  /dev/sdc: read failed after 0 of 1024 at 4096: Input/output error 
  /dev/sdd: read failed after 0 of 1024 at 0: Input/output error 
  /dev/sdd: read failed after 0 of 1024 at 2499819012096: Input/output error 
  /dev/sdd: read failed after 0 of 1024 at 2499819130880: Input/output error 
  /dev/sdd: read failed after 0 of 1024 at 4096: Input/output error 
  /dev/sde: read failed after 0 of 1024 at 0: Input/output error

I can create pvs, lvms, and vgs, but this always appears,
can anyone please help me?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you probably have a physical disk error.

You need to run some disk checking tools. The one I use is quite expensive I'm afraid but can recover most errors that *can* be recovered. It is [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com).

Comment: it it ok to wipeout the disks clean then try to map it again? or do i really need to recover it?

Comment: You can wipe the disks if you don't need the data on them. Most likely that *will* get rid of the error. Most such errors are transitory.

Comment: ok ill do that 1st, then will make a follow up after, thanks a lot for the reply :)

Comment: its still there. the issue on that is still there

Comment: When you reformatted, did you create it as a simple volume rather than LVM?

Comment: havent created anything yet, i think the problem is within the multipath?

Comment: mpatht (36782bcb0003585ae00000b245303b751) dm-0 DELL,MD32xx
size=4.5T features='3 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50' hwhandler='1 rdac' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=6 status=active
| `- 2:0:1:0 sdb 8:16 active ready running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  `- 2:0:0:0 sda 8:0  active ghost running

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you potentially have multiple paths to the disks.  When you have LVM configured on multipathed devices you have to tell /etc/lvm/lvm.conf to point to the multipath reference.

What it is doing is attempting to use each disk when it should be using /dev/multipath_dev.

In your /etc/lvm/lvm.conf there should be an item for filter.  Look at that line and work on getting that to match up to the proper devices.  Once that is done you can use pvs to see if what you have is right.  There is some trial and error when doing this sometimes.

Comment: oh i see, will do this when i get back and will reply soon after, thank you very much!